# R: How do I replace \\ with /?

Tags: regex, r

In R I have a string  like

```
file = "c:\\hello\\nihao"
```

How do I replace all the \ with /? The ?gsub documentation is really confusing! You should get extra points for pointing to a good R regex resource!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not just use the `fixed = TRUE` argument?

```
gsub("\\", "/", file, fixed=TRUE)
# [1] "c:/hello/nihao"
```

Alternatively:

```
gsub("\\\\", "/", file)
# [1] "c:/hello/nihao"
```

Answer (score 9):

Some ways to avoid wearing out your `\` key:

```
paste(dirname(file),basename(file),sep="/")
[1] "c:/hello/nihao"

normalizePath(file,"/",mustWork=FALSE)
[1] "c:/hello/nihao"
```

Comment: `normalizePath` was the one I was thinking of too, but couldn't remember it. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
gsub('\\\\', '/', str)
```